# c# wpf treeviewitem with contextmenu

Tags: c#, wpf

i just want to make right click menucontext with normal treeviewitem.
all example i can find , it ask to bind with something . but i just don't want to bind any thing .

for example:

```
            TreeViewItem ceo = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "CEO" };
            TreeViewItem manager1 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Manager1" };
            TreeViewItem manager2 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Manager2" };
            TreeViewItem person1 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "person1" };
            TreeViewItem person2 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "person2" };

            manager1.Items.Add(person1);
            manager2.Items.Add(person2);
            ceo.Items.Add(manager1);
            ceo.Items.Add(manager2);
```

i just want to make the subnode menucontext , can we?

Comment: create contextmenu instance for each item is a bad idea...

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a `Style` to accomplish this in a comfortable way. Place this `Style` into a `ResourceDictionary` within the scope of the `TreeView` so that you can easily find it or in case of an implicit `Style` that it can apply automatically.

The following implicit `Style` will add the same `ContextMenu` to all `TreeViewItems`:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
              <MenuItem Header="_Bold"
                        IsCheckable="True"
                        Checked="Bold_Checked"
                        Unchecked="Bold_Unchecked" />
              <MenuItem Header="_Italic"
                        IsCheckable="True"
                        Checked="Italic_Checked"
                        Unchecked="Italic_Unchecked" />
              <Separator />
              <MenuItem Header="Increase Font Size"
                        Click="IncreaseFont_Click" />
              <MenuItem Header="_Decrease Font Size"
                        Click="DecreaseFont_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Alternatively (but not recommended) you can create the `Style` and the `ContextMenu` using C# and assign the `Style` to each `TreeViewItem` manually or as well add it to a `ResourceDictionary` e.g. `Application.Current.Resources`. But it is more complicated and less readable than using XAML.